# Why does ((0)) cause a Bash script to exit if `set -e` directive is present?

Tags: bash, shell

This outputs `before\n`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

echo before
((0))
echo after
```

Removing `set -e` or changing `((0))` to `((1))` makes the program output `before\nafter\n` as expected.

Why does `((0))` trigger the `set -e` exit condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will explain:

```
((0))
echo $?
1

((1))
echo $?
0
```

So it is due to non-zero return status of arithmetic expression evaluation in `(( and ))` your script is exiting when `set -e` is being used.

As `help set` says this:

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 2):

Line

```
 set -e
```

means:
`-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.` (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

`((0))` is an expression that evaluates to `1`. That's why the script exits.

Comment: "if a command exits with a non-zero status"  and "that evaluates to 0. That's why the script exits." do not fit.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, in a numeric context, 0 is false. false == failure. That's why `(( 0 ))` (numeric context) is different from `( exit 0; )` (standard exit-status context).

Comment: Yes, but in shell context, 0 is success. And the other answer shows that `((0))` evaluates to 1 == failure. Paying attention to this difference is crucial for answering the question. Maybe it was just a typo by @Dariusz, at least I believe we agree that `((0)) is an expression that evaluates to 0` is difficult to understand without further explanation.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke thank you, it was indeed a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, yes, but putting the shell into a numeric context is the entire point of `(( ))`, which is _why_ evaluating that expression to an exit status of 1 is the proper thing for a shell to implement -- it's translating out from a numeric context (inside) to a shell context (outside).